# Issuse with adding FadeIn/Out effect when changing image on list item hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover, html-lists, fade

I have successfully created menu with an option to change photo by menu list item hover.
But i have an issue to add fade in/out effect when photos are changing from one to another.

here is the code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <img src="menu1.jpg" alt="">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-image="menu1.jpg" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-image="menu2.jpg" href="#">Another item</a></li>
        <li><a data-image="menu3.jpg" href="#">One more item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /#menu -->

<script>
    var image = $('#menu').find('img').attr('src');
        $('#menu ul li a').mouseover(function() {
            var currentImage = $(this).attr('data-image');
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('img').attr('src', currentImage);

        });
</script>
```

I tried something like this but no luck

```
$('#menu ul li a').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('img').hide().attr('src', currentImage).fadeIn(2000);
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('img').fadeOut(2000,function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('src', currentImage).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your JS Script with :

- you need to call the image by an ID or a class name: `id="loadImage"`
- for fading first **hide** the image and then `.fadeIn();`

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-image="1.jpg" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-image="2.jpg" href="#">Another item</a></li>
        <li><a data-image="3.jpg" href="#">One more item</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="" id="loadImage">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu ul li a').on("mouseover", function() {
        var currentImage = $(this).attr('data-image');
        $("#loadImage").attr('src', currentImage).hide().fadeIn();
    });
});
```